# Twitter Bootstrap span and rows

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a very simple question about using Twitter Bootstrap. If I want to display large blocks, what choice is better?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span10">..</div>
  <div class="span10">..</div>
  <div class="span10">..</div>
  .....
</div>
```

Or

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span10">..</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span10">..</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span10">..</div>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot. I know this is a too simple question but I'm starting to use this framework and I want to use efficiently.

Comment: Well, what do you want ? Large blocks is a bit vague. http://jsfiddle.net/UHMjS/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't changed bootstrap's configuration, your screen is divided in only 12 parts. Thus, your first option is not *natural* because you try to use 30 parts.

Go for the second one, where the division in different rows is explicit.